# How to merge duplicate data in a single array/dictionary and return values?

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I've written a VBA macro for CorelDraw that loops through selected objects and returns values as a string. I want it to be able to handle duplicate data better, for example if two objects have the same size, it should return

```
"2 of 10 x 10"
```

instead of

```
"1 of 10 x 10"
"1 of 10 x 10"
```

Coming from Ruby (specifically thinking of hashes), I'm thinking that the macro should loop through the selected range, add (object.sizeWidth, object.sizeHeight) data as strings to an array/dictionary where it should be checked for duplicates and count them. I don't know what's best or how to set/check their values.

Here is my code so far

```
Sub objectsToString()

Dim str As String
Dim v As Shape, vr As ShapeRange
Dim xSize#, ySize#
Dim dupCount As Integer

str = ""
Set vr = ActiveSelectionRange

    For Each v In vr
    dupCount = 'value assigned via iteration
    xSize = v.SizeWidth
    ySize = v.SizeHeight
    str = str & dupCount & " of " & xSize & " x " & ySize & vbNewLine

    Next v

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scripting.dictionary using the shape name as key for example, and use it's .exists method then have the item as the count and have a separate dictionary with the same key name, and then have a class/type/array/collection/dictionary with the dimensions in.

Something like this would be a good start.

```
Sub x()

Dim a() As Variant
Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim v As Variant

a = Array("10 x 10", "20 x 20", "30 x 30", "10 x 10")

Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary

For Each v In a

    If Not d.Exists(v) Then
        d.Add v, 1
    Else
        d(v) = d(v) + 1
    End If

Next v

For Each v In d.Keys

    Debug.Print d(v) & " of " & v

Next v

End Sub
```

Gives the result

2 of 10 x 10

1 of 20 x 20

1 of 30 x 30

Comment: My understanding is that arrays need to be set with a given length. Can this be done dynamically using vr.count as per my original code example?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav You should move the contents of your comment into the question if they are relevant to the answer. Comments are ephemeral and not an appropriate place to provide a solution.

Comment: The `for....each` loop will sort itself out from the start of the array to the end, you can say from lbound to ubound.